# How to pronounce grades in US and UK schools?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

Grades in school reports are expressed through letters followed or not by a sign like "plus" or "minus". Please how do you pronounce grades like A+ or A-, B+ or C-? I have also heard the phrase "straight A", what does it mean?

Comment: In the UK we say 'plus' for the + sign, and 'minus' for the - sign. I suspect it is the same in US schools. In US English, a 'straight A' student is one who has achieved an A grades in every subject taken.

Comment: But why the word "straight"? Is it because it is a block letter? Or does it refer the the + sign?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: to get straight As in American English.  You pronounce it like the alphabet and plus or minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK we say 'plus' for the + sign, and 'minus' for the - sign. I suspect it is the same in US schools.

[Pronounce mathematical symbols](http://www.uefap.com/speaking/symbols/symbols.htm)

In US English, a 'straight A' student is one who has achieved an A grades in every subject taken. We can use 'straight', mainly informally. to mean 'following one after another without an interruption; consecutive'. A football team that has played five games and won all of them could be said to have won 'five straight games'. Similarly a student who has scored As in every subject in a term, year, or during their school career has scored 'straight As', and is a 'straight-A student'.

[Straight (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straight)

Comment: I've thought, or do now purposely cogitate, that straight A's refers to the column of A's on a report card. What do you think? Anyway, straight A's is a synonym for All A's.

Comment: Nothing to do with straightness of layout such as on a report card, I think. Just 'straight' meaning 'unbroken or consecutive', of a series.

Comment: well, I've always connected the word and the report